# how to return in a mysql function

Tags: mysql, function

Hy, I have the following function on my mysql schema, this function should work like this:

```
  if (especie=mEspecie && variedad=mVariedad) then
         then return precio;   else
         return 0; 
  end if;
```

but somehow it's not working, anybody can help me here?.

this is my function, I've updated since @vipin answer:

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `BUSCA_PRECIO_MATRIZ`(mEspecie int, mVariedad int) RETURNS int(11)
    READS SQL DATA
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
declare precio, especie,variedad integer;
declare cur1 cursor for
select ifnull(valor,0),idconf_especie,idconf_variedad from cc_matriz_precios_facturacion_recibidor where idconf_especie=mEspecie and idconf_variedad=mVariedad;

open cur1;
    loop_cur : loop 
        fetch cur1 into precio,especie,variedad;
            if(especie = mEspecie) then
                if  (variedad = mVariedad) then
                    return variedad;
                    LEAVE loop_cur;
                else
                    return variedad;
                    leave loop_cur;
                end if;
            end if;
    end loop;
    return 0;
close cur1;
return 0;
END
```

Comment: why you written again and again return 0 or 1 ? what you want to write in procedure ?

Comment: want it to return 0 if not found or precio if found

Comment: so why you write cursor for it ? you can use it by only select query. i am update my query

Comment: because I use the result on other query's so I just wanted to call the function

Comment: maybe it is because Im comparing a string from my cursor with a int value from my function arguments???

Comment: i have updated my answer please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my query, if any data found in cc_matriz_precios_facturacion_recibidor table after check condition then its return true other wise its return false

```
    CREATE FUNCTION `BUSCA_PRECIO_MATRIZ`(mEspecie int, mVariedad int) RETURNS int(11)
        READS SQL DATA
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    declare precio, especie,variedad, flag int;    

    select valor,idconf_especie,idconf_variedad, 1 into precio, especie,variedad, flag 
    from cc_matriz_precios_facturacion_recibidor
    where idconf_especie=mEspecie and idconf_variedad=mVariedad;
    IF(flag) THEN 
         return 1; 
    ELSE 
         return 0;
    END IF;
    END
```

or in short

```
CREATE FUNCTION `BUSCA_PRECIO_MATRIZ`(mEspecie int, mVariedad int) RETURNS int(11)
            READS SQL DATA
            DETERMINISTIC
        BEGIN
        declare precio, especie,variedad int;   
        DECLARE flag int default 0;

        select valor,idconf_especie,idconf_variedad, 1 into precio, especie,variedad, flag 
        from cc_matriz_precios_facturacion_recibidor
        where idconf_especie=mEspecie and idconf_variedad=mVariedad;
        return flag;
        END
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it keep throwing the same response 'OK'
I updated my function

Answer (score 1):

Another option which simplifies its function is:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `BUSCA_PRECIO_MATRIZ`//

CREATE FUNCTION `BUSCA_PRECIO_MATRIZ` (
    `mEspecie` INT,
    `mVariedad` INT
)
RETURNS BOOL
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM `cc_matriz_precios_facturacion_recibidor`
                   WHERE `idconf_especie` = `mEspecie` AND
                         `idconf_variedad` = `mVariedad`);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```